# prove $a^6 + b^6 + c^6 + 3a^2b^2c^2 > 2(a^3b^3+b^3c^3+c^3a^3)$ using Popoviciu's inequality.

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove $a^6 + b^6 + c^6 + 3a^2b^2c^2 > 2(a^3b^3+b^3c^3+c^3a^3)$ for $a, b, c$ positive numbers not all equal using Popoviciu's inequality.

The equality states the following: Let $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on the real inverval $I$. $f$ is convex if and only if
$\frac{f(x)+f(y)+f(z)}{3} + f\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right) \geq \frac{2}{3}\left[f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) + f\left(\frac{y+z}{2}\right)+ f\left(\frac{z+x}{2}\right)\right]$
for all $x, y, z \in I.$

Can anyone get me a hint how to find a convex function with the desired property? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The form of Popoviciu's inequality is very similar to your inequality to be proven in this form: $$f(x) + f(y) +f(z) + 3f\left(\frac {x+y+z}3\right) \ge 2 \left[f\left(\frac {x+y}2\right)+f\left(\frac {y+z}2\right)+f\left(\frac {z+x}2\right)\right]$$

Comparing this to

$$a^6+b^6+c^6+3a^2b^2c^2>2(a^3b^3+b^3c^3+c^3a^3)$$

It seems that this $f$ takes the power $6$ and divides it across the variables, and addition becomes multiplication:

e.g. $f(x)=a^6, f(y) = b^6, f\left(\frac x2+\frac y2\right) = a^3b^3$

Do you know a kind of functions that does this? The constraint $a,b,c>0$ is another hint.

Hint 2: Consider the function $f(x)=e^{6x}$. We have

$$e^{6x}+e^{6y}+e^{6z}+3e^{2x}e^{2y}e^{2z}\ge2(e^{3x}e^{3y}+e^{3y}e^{3z}+e^{3z}e^{3x})$$

What happens if you take $x = \ln \dots$?

Comment: Thanks! I think it has to be an exponential function like $f(x)=a^x$ but I am still stuck because then they all have base $a$, but they should all be different.

Comment: I added an additional hint.

Comment: if we take $x= \ln(a)$ the we get that $e^{6x} = e^{6 \ln(a)} = a^6$. now I see it. Thanks a lot.